# Asymptotic differential equation for large $t$. Can I just drop fast decaying terms?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, approximation

I am looking at the differential equation

$x'(t)=x(t) (1+s(t))$.

and I want to make a statement about the behaviour of its solution $x(t)$ for large $t$, knowing that for large $t$

$s(t)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2t}+\text{terms decaying like }t^{-2}\text{ or faster}.$

Naively I would simply drop the higher order terms, since I know that for large enough $t$ those should be negligible. Setting $s(t)\approx\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2t}$ and solve the resulting differential equation, yields

$x(t)\propto e^{3t/2}/\sqrt t$.

Is this way of approximating the differential equation and its solution for large $t$ legal? If not, why not, and what else could I say about the solution $x(t)$ for large $t$, given the asymptotic behaviour of $s(t)$?

Comment: What is the function $s(t)$ in closed form? Usually you would solve the differential equation and then get an asmptotic approximation.

Comment: I cannot give an analytic expression for it. I only can give this asymptotic expansion for large $t$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x > 0$, you can write your differential equation as

$$ \dfrac{d}{dt} \log(x(t)) = 1 + s(t)$$
so
$$ \log(x(t)) = c + \int (1+s(t))\; dt = c + \frac{3}{2} t - \frac{1}{2} \log t + O(t^{-1})$$
That is, there exist $T$ and $\epsilon$ such that for all $t > T$,

$$ c + \frac{3}{2} t - \frac{1}{2}\log t - \frac{\epsilon}{t} < \log(x(t))
<  c + \frac{3}{2} t - \frac{1}{2}\log t +   \frac{\epsilon}{t}$$

Now take the exponential...

Comment: Hi there thanks for help! Ok, after taking the exponential I have $\tilde c\frac{\exp (3t/2)}{\sqrt t}e^{-\epsilon /t}<x(t)<\tilde c\frac{\exp (3t/2)}{\sqrt t}e^{\epsilon /t}$. For large $t$, $e^{\pm\epsilon /t}$ is approximately $1$, and hence what I got as a result is justified. Is that line of thought correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: That is great! I understand now. Thank you very much again! You have been very helpful!